# Domain name consisting of country name

Tags: domain-name

There are a lot of top-level domains consisting only of the name of a country, like:

- [canada.com](https://canada.com)
- [russia.com](https://russia.com)
- [india.com](https://india.com),
- [africa.com](https://africa.com), etc.

Some are registered for news websites and other for travel websites.

Is it globally legal to use the name of a country as the name of a domain ?
Are there any cyber laws / legal forces that restrict/describe what can you use as the name of a domain ?

Comment: Domain names are the complete string ("canada.com", not just "canada") and they read in reverse order; the top level domain (TLD) is "com", followed by "india". So, some registrar allow to register domains in the "com" TLD, others may allow to register in the "in" (India) or "ca" (Canada) TLD, and AFAIK the rules are defined for each TLD. Laws apply to name domains, but it is almost always related to trademarks (do not register peps1.com or p3psi.com or pepsi.in unless you are PEPSI, or you will get sued fast).

Comment: Can you give an example of a top-level domain that consists only of the name of a country? I cannot think of one, at least not among the well-known ccTLDs, gTLDs, sTLDs, or uTLDs. ccTLDs use ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 codes, not country names. gTLDs use generic monikers like "biz", "org", "com", etc. In fact, the TLD you listed in your question does not correspond to the name of any country I know of.